# Difference of limit points and isolated points in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

e.g. find the limit and isolated points of sets $(0, 1]\cup\{2\}$ and $\{1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and in $\mathbb{R}$.
I think in $\mathbb{R}$ limit point of $(0, 1]\cup\{2\}$ is [0, 1], isolated point is 2, and for $\{1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ limit point is 0, and every point in the set is a isolated point.
But if the two set are in $\mathbb{Q}$, would the conclusion change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(0,1] \cup \{2\}$ considered as a subset of $\Bbb Q$ we actually mean
$((0,1] \cap \Bbb Q) \cup \{2\}$, I suppose.

In $\Bbb R$ the limit points are indeed $[0,1]$ but in $\Bbb Q$ it will be $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$. The point $2$ is isolated in both cases.

$\{\frac1n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ is already entirely a subset of $\Bbb Q$ and its only limit point in either case is $0$, the rest are isolated.